# Using Azure Service Bus for industrial control (Windows CE) behind a firewall

Tags: wcf, azure, windows-ce, servicebus, azureservicebus

I'm looking at an industrial-control system design which calls for embedded computers (headless Windows CE 5.x boxes) running behind a NAT which control various tools (e.g. a printer, security lights, single-shot cameras, etc).

These devices are controlled by a system hosted on Azure and are typically sat behind a NAT, which means they need to establish an outbound connection to an Azure service bus, I think.

These embedded, Windows CE-based computers would be both clients (to send reporting data back to the service bus) but also provide services of their own (e.g. the headless computer controlling the lights would have a `TurnLightsOn()` service method which the service, via the service-bus, would invoke).

The problem is twofold:

1. As far as I can tell, the Azure Service Bus feature only supports WCF services.
2. Windows CE cannot host WCF services, it can only be a client for WCF.

How can Windows Azure services be used to solve this problem?

Workarounds exist: to use TCP with an application protocol of my own design that connects directly to my Worker role without any Service Bus between them (but Azure provides automatic load-balancing between Worker instances).

The other option is to move from Windows CE to Windows Embedded, but that adds complexity (as many of the machines being used have built-in Windows CE computers, using Windows Embedded would require the addition of new physical machines which would need to be maintained).

Comment: I'm guessing the ServiceBus SDK is based off of WCF?? I thought you could also doe REST type calls avoiding the need for the service bus SDK all together, just takes more work.

Comment: @Mikee that doesn't solve the problem of 2-way communication. Also, how is WinCE going to host REST services?

Comment: Sorry, I guess I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime there is a Azure IoT Device SDK, and Toradex ported it also for WinCE, maybe this helps.

http://developer.toradex.com/knowledge-base/azure-iot

https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdks/blob/develop/c/doc/run_sample_on_toradex_wec2013.md